# Python: httplib getresponse issues many recv() calls

Tags: python, python-2.7, httplib

`getresponse` issues many `recv` calls while reading header of an HTML request. It actually issues `recv` for each byte which results in many system calls. How can it be optimized?

I verified on an Ubuntu machine with strace dump.

**sample code:**

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.python.org")
conn.request("HEAD", "/index.html")
r1 = conn.getresponse()
```

**strace dump:**

```
sendto(3, "HEAD /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:"..., 78, 0, NULL, 0) = 78
recvfrom(3, "H", 1, 0, NULL, NULL)      = 1
recvfrom(3, "T", 1, 0, NULL, NULL)      = 1
recvfrom(3, "T", 1, 0, NULL, NULL)      = 1
recvfrom(3, "P", 1, 0, NULL, NULL)      = 1
recvfrom(3, "/", 1, 0, NULL, NULL)      = 1
...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
r = conn.getresponse(buffering=True)
```

On Python 3.1+ there is no `buffering` parameter (it is default).

Comment: I'm getting a lot of recvfrom() reading single byte each using urllib2.urlopen. I found that urllib2 uses HTTPConnection inside, but no arguments are being passed in getreponse() call. Is there any way to get rid of enormous amount of tiny recvfrom()'s ?

Comment: @AndreiBelov Have you tried to use HTTPConnection directly and pass `buffering=True` to its getresponse() method?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian unfortunately, it's not an option. I've just figured out that urllib2 reads 1-byte chunks only for response headers, i.e. when server starts to send body in chunked encoding, things look better:

   323 recvfrom(3, "\r", 1, 0, NULL, NULL)     = 1
   324 recvfrom(3, "\n", 1, 0, NULL, NULL)     = 1
   325 recvfrom(3, "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en-U"..., 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 8192